# Image not showing in HTML without prefixing "file:///"

Tags: html, image

In class as teacher was teaching about relative path and absolute path in `html` for `img` tag , relative path was working fine like `img` `src= "..\pictures\sun.jpg"` However in absolute path which was like `img` `src= "C:\users\pictures\sun.jpg"` .....

This thing was displaying image on most of the computers but not displaying on a few computers including mine. Then we prefixed `"file:///"` before `'C'` and it started working. My doubt is why in some computers it worked without the prefix and how can i too can display the image on html page without using prefix?

I have searched on internet about this but could not found any satisfactory answer. Either they say it will not work without `"file:///"` (then why it is working without `"file:///"` in most of the computers?) Or they suggest me to use relative path(that I know already). I just wanted to know where lies the secret of this difference?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use backslashes, use forward slashes.

Instead of this:

```
'img src= "..\pictures\sun.jpg
```

Do this:

```
img src= "../pictures/sun.jpg
```